# 「一緒なように」は不自然かどうか

Tags: usage, adverbs

今日仕事で、出張の日程についてメールを書きました。三人が同じ学会で発表しますが、一人一人は違う場所から出発します。一人目の分も二人目の分も日程をきちんと書いていましたが、三人目については省略しようと思い、このように書きました。

> X先生は国際便が一緒に乗るようにして、X街からの便が多くのため、私は決めることができません。

= X-sensei should be on the same international flight, but since there are many flights from his city, I cannot decide for him.

多分これも間違いがあるのではないかと思いますが、ここで質問したいのは、下書きで書いて結局送らなかった、次の別案についてです。

> X先生は国際便を一緒なようにして、...

= X-sensei should be put with us on the same international flight (かな)

この「一緒なように」は日本語として不自然だったり、意味が通らない表現でしょうか。

（もちろん、この質問の日本語への訂正もご遠慮なく）

---

Today, during work, I was writing an e-mail about a business trip's itinerary. There are three of us presenting a the same conference, but each of us is going from a different city. I wrote out the first person's plan and the second person's plan, but I wanted to abbreviate the third person's plan. I wrote a sentence like this:

> X先生は国際便が一緒に乗るようにして、X街からの便が多くのため、私は決めることができません。

While there are probably grammatical problems with that sentence, my question is about a different thought I had in draft I didn't send where I wrote the following sentence:

> X先生は国際便を一緒なようにして、...

My question is whether 一緒なように is unnatural and/or incomprehensible Japanese.

(Of course corrections to the Japanese in the question are appreciated).

Comment: Could you provide English translations for your Japanese sentences?

Comment: I'd like it too. 一緒なように on its own isn't necessarily unnatural, but I couldn't get the meaning of your email part.

Comment: okay here's what i was going for ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

日本語でのご質問ですので、日本語で回答させていただきます。

---

ご質問にあるような状況において「一緒なように」という表現を用いることは、不自然だと思います。意味は伝わりますが……。

仕事で、相手に何か行動を促したり、目的となる状態や行動を伝えたり等する場合に使う「〜ように」という表現は、一般的には、**動詞の後**に用います。「**動詞＋ように**」という言い方をすると、伝える内容が明確になりますし、また、くだけていない話し方に聞こえるからです。

「一緒な」は「な形容詞」です。な形容詞の後に直接「〜ように」をつけると、動詞が省略されているように感じる場合が多いです。くだけた表現になっている印象です。

例えば、

> Ａ「この機能をより**便利に使えるように**改良して、新商品として発売しましょう。」
>
> Ｂ「この機能をより**便利なように**改良して、新商品として発売しましょう。」

このふたつの文は、意味はほぼ同じですが、Ａのほうがより社会人らしい、きちんとした話し方をしている印象です。

漢字に直接「な」をつける種類の な形容詞等を、礼儀の求められる場や仕事で使う場合には、少々注意が必要です。

「漢字＋な」という表現は、歴史的にみると比較的新しい言い方で、まだ完全には社会に浸透していないものもあるからです。まだ大多数の人々に受け入れられていない用法は、俗語的に聞こえたり、くだけた表現と思われたりします。

仕事でも使える「漢字＋な」には、例えば以下の語があります。

> **便利な**機能、**不便な**ドア、**大変な**事態、**簡単な**作業、**有名な**アプリ、
>
> **安全な**環境、**特別な**日、**不思議な**出来事、**親切な**言葉、**自由な**時間、
>
> **無理な**お願い、**丁寧な**挨拶、**親密な**関係、**極端な**話、**精密な**機械、
>
> **必要な**経費、**清潔な**服装、**着実な**進歩、**身近な**人、他多数

日常会話で使うことはありますが、仕事で用いるには適切でない、くだけた表現と思われがちな「漢字＋な」の例は、

> **一緒な**友達 → 「一緒の友達」「一緒にいる友達」「同じ友達」
>
> **普通な**会話 → 「普通の会話」
>
> **我慢な**時 → 「我慢の時」「我慢する時」
>
> **(地名)な**人 → 「(地名)在住の人」「(地名)出身の人」

等があります。このような表現の中には、厳密に言えば、な形容詞に分類されないものもあります。右側に表記したものが、仕事でも使える適切な表現になります。

「漢字＋送りがな」という形の語は、その言葉自体が適切であれば、「な形容詞化することで不適切な表現に変わる」という可能性は、ほぼありません。

> **静かな**郊外、**鮮やかな**色、**爽やかな**笑顔、
>
> **好きな**仕事、**嫌いな**飲み物、
>
> **大げさな**言い方、**切れ切れな**声、
>
> 何か**言いたげな**表情、他多数

これには、もともと漢字である語を平仮名で表記したものは、当てはまりません。例えば、「一緒な友人」を「一しょな友人」と書いても、仕事で使える適切な表現にはなりません。

---

メール文についてですが、私でしたら、このように書くと思います。

> 国際線は、Ｘ先生も同じ便にお乗りいただくかたちで【手配いたしました。／ 手配する予定です。】
>
> 国内線のＣ空港発・Ｄ空港着の便は多数あるため、Ｘ先生のご都合に合う便をお選びいただくと良いかと思います。

Comment: すごく分かりやすい説明してくださって、ありがとうございます。「くだけた」という印象を残る表現です。また、正しいメールの書き方もありがたいです。

Answer (score 3):

(I still don't really get the situation where you leave a different city and nevertheless board on the same plane, however ...)

One example I now come up with is Ｘ先生と一緒の国際便に**なるように***したいのですが、先生の街からの便がたくさんあって (or あるので)、どれにすればいいか わかりません.

(* I edited according to what's noticed in the comment)

X先生と国際便 <s>を</s> が 一緒なようにしたいのですが works too.

To translate "X-sensei should be on the same international flight" as straightforwardly as possible, you can do it to Ｘ先生は一緒の国際便に乗ることになっているのですが.

<s>Here, X先生は(国際)便を一緒にすることに… works too. But making the sentence obscure with …なように seems pointless to me.</s>

Comment: Board on the same plane as in we are each *first* flying on a different plane, then connecting in TYO and boarding the sam international flight (our university has multiple campuses). / Also, while I do appreciate the fix to the sentence used, my main question is about the usability of 一緒なよう and whether that sounds unnatural.